# Дебаг для Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, отладка

Есть ли какой то способ ставить брейкпойнты, ватчить переменные, и смотреть колл стек. На обычном JS все просто, но когда разворачиванию проект с помощью vue-cli. То что то я сразу потерялся. Через дев сервер же это еще все работает.

Comment: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/debugging-in-vscode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если разворачиваете через vue-cli, то там есть сорсмэпы из коробки, которые позволяют ставить брейкпоинты в DevTools там, где вам это нужно. Заходите в папку webpack, там находятся ваши исходники в том виде, в котором они находятся у вас в файловой системе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, это то что я и искал.

Answer (score 1):

> На обычном JS все просто

А вы на Vue пишете на необычном JS? Вставляете `debugger;` где надо и добро пожаловать в отладчик в Dev Tools браузера.

Comment: Ну `debugger` вряд ли будет полезен, учитывая, что код, прежде чем попасть в браузер, проходит через тысячи всевозможных модификаций (системы сборки, транспиляторы и т.п.).

Answer (score 0):

Странно, что никто этого здесь еще не упомянул, но советую взглянуть на [официальное расширение для Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd). Также поможет в дебаге vue-router и vuex.

Comment: Ну просто подразумевалось, что разработчик, который пишет на Vue уже использует это расширение ))

Comment: нужны именно брейкпоинты. Расширение это ясное дело что по умолчанию надо ставить.